# Data Validation Comma Separated String is including Cell's original Contents (embedded 0) in list

Tags: excel, vba, string, validation

I have been trying to figure this out on my own for way too long. I have a two columns running a worksheet change event that puts data validation selections in a comma separated lists. Each of the cells have 0 in them to make the cell title appear when the cell is empty (this has to stay) the problem is that when I select the data validation options the original cell contents (0) is the first value in the comma separated string. Can someone help me embed code that will exclude the original cell contents as "oldvalue." It doesn't matter to me if its a .clearcontents at the beginning of the change event or if the 0 is excluded from the string later on... Thanks in advance! Here is the code and a few pics for reference....

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim rg As Range

    Set rg = Range("A1:K400")

    rg.Replace What:="", Replacement:="0", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False

Next_Part:

    Dim Oldvalue As String

    Dim Newvalue As String

    Application.EnableEvents = True
    On Error GoTo Exitsub

        If Target.Column = 9 Or Target.Column = 11 Then
 
        If Target.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation) Is Nothing Then

            GoTo Exitsub
     
            Else: If Target.Value = "" Then GoTo Exitsub Else

                Application.EnableEvents = False

                Newvalue = Target.Value

                Application.Undo
                Oldvalue = Target.Value

                If Oldvalue = "" Then

                Target.Value = Newvalue

            Else

                If InStr(1, Oldvalue, Newvalue) = 0 Then

                Target.Value = Oldvalue & ", " & Newvalue
          
            Else:

            Target.Value = Oldvalue

            End If

        End If

    End If

End If

Application.EnableEvents = True

Exitsub:

Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

[screensnip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rIkft.jpg)